# function declaration in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'm a beginner to UI5 and I couldn't find an answer to the following question:
Why in UI5 functions are declared this way:
[image: Right way]

and I can't declare it this way:
[image: Wrong way]

I couldn't find any JavaScript resource that shows the first picture function declaration .
thanks

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: What you show is a [Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_expressions), which declares an anonymous function, assigned to the property `CloseAlertsPopover` of an [Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#object_literals). The issue you have is that you place a ["normal" function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_declarations) inside an Object Literal, and that is simply not a valid Object Literal!

Answer (score 1):

This is how JS works. Everything can be referenced by everything. It is best practise to organise functions into objects. The `extend` method returns in the end an object.

I recommend you to disallow normal declaration with the esLint rule [func-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style#enforce-the-consistent-use-of-either-function-declarations-or-expressions-func-style) set to `expression`.

I put every combination into an example

```
sap.ui.define([ "...BaseController", "sap/base/Log" ], function( BaseController, Log
) {
    "use strict";
    // "normal function definition", exists within the outer {}
    function normal(){  }
    // function expression, exists within the outer {}
    const functionExpression = function(){  };

    // this is basically: return { onInit : ()=>{}, ... }
    return BaseController.extend("controller.Detail", {
        onInit: function() {
            // constructor call
            BaseController.prototype.onInit.apply(this, arguments);
            // extend makes sure that 'this' points to the controller
            this.objectLiteralWithPointerTofunction.call(this);
            // prints 1
            console.log(this.objectLiteralWithBasicIntValue);
        },
        objectLiteralWithBasicIntValue: 1,
        // object literal pointing to a function
        objectLiteralWithPointerTofunction: function(){
           // nested code can access the outer definitions
           normal();
           functionExpression();
           // you can nest as deep as you want
           const functionExpression2 = ()=>{};
        }
    });
});
// you can NOT call anywhere else the nested functions !!!
normal();
functionExpression();
functionExpression2()
```

Answer (score -5):

you can declare a function any way you wish, but usually, in sapui5 we extend some control and we write code inside it so when you declare a function inside a class or object right way to declare is

```
{
   demo : function(){
   }
}
```

not

```
{
   function demo(){
   }
}
```